# Camel route with AMQP consumer runs ok in Eclipse, hangs in karaf

Tags: java, apache-camel, amqp, apache-karaf, karaf

I am using Camel 2.17.3 and karaf 4.0.7 (also tried 4.0.1).

I have a Camel route that runs fine in Eclipse when a junit test starts it, but hangs when deployed to karaf. If I change the amqp: 'from' component to timer: the route runs fine in karaf.

My AMQP setup in the routebuilder is:

```
   @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        getContext().addComponent("amqp", AMQPComponent.amqpComponent(String.format("amqp://%s:%s?amqp.saslMechanisms=ANONYMOUS", AMQP_SERVICE_HOST, AMQP_SERVICE_PORT)));
```

Even this route will hang karaf, and run fine in Eclipse:

```
 from("amqp:queue:myqueue").routeId("myRoute")
 .log("temp")
```

In Karaf, when I say "hang", I observe these things:

- If I try to exit karaf, it hangs - I need to kill the process.
- If I try to stop the bundle, karaf hangs - I need to kill the process.
- Neither camel:context-list nor camel:route-list return anything
- I do not get a "route consuming from..." message in the log. This is all
  the output from starting the bundle:

> 2016-10-08 23:46:00,593 | INFO  | nsole user karaf | bundle
>   | 90 - org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle - 1.0.1 | Bundle
>   Considered for SPI providers: mis-routes 2016-10-08 23:46:00,593 |
>   INFO  | nsole user karaf | bundle                           | 90 -
>   org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle - 1.0.1 | No 'SPI-Provider'
>   Manifest header. Skipping bundle: mis-routes 2016-10-08 23:46:05,595 |
>   INFO  | ool-130-thread-1 | OsgiDefaultCamelContext          | 56 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.3 | Apache Camel 2.17.3
>   (CamelContext: mis-routes) is starting 2016-10-08 23:46:05,599 | INFO 
>   | ool-130-thread-1 | OsgiDefaultCamelContext          | 56 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.3 | MDC logging is enabled on
>   CamelContext: mis-routes 2016-10-08 23:46:05,601 | INFO  |
>   ool-130-thread-1 | ManagedManagementStrategy        | 56 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.3 | JMX is enabled 2016-10-08
>   23:46:05,708 | INFO  | ool-130-thread-1 |
>   DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry   | 56 - org.apache.camel.camel-core -
>   2.17.3 | Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
>   2016-10-08 23:46:05,804 | INFO  | ool-130-thread-1 |
>   OsgiDefaultCamelContext          | 56 - org.apache.camel.camel-core -
>   2.17.3 | AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as
>   it may improve performance. 2016-10-08 23:46:05,805 | INFO  |
>   ool-130-thread-1 | OsgiDefaultCamelContext          | 56 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.3 | StreamCaching is not in use. If
>   using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more
>   details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you deploying this to Karaf? As a bundle? Are the camel-amqp dependencies also deployed? I have deployed camel-rabbitmq and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason should be related to this issue in Camel JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10278

The main problem is proton-j 0.10 is incompatible with qpid-jms-client version 0.8. We upgraded the dependency to proton-j 0.12.0 and the fix will be available in the Camel 2.17.4 release.

For the moment you can use Camel 2.17.4-SNAPSHOT or upgrade the dependency in the Camel-Amqp Karaf feature.